# Grails plugin packages images into the wrong folder

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have a plugin that has this path in `web-apps`: `/images/icons/`. There are a few png files in there. When I run `grails run-app` on the plugin, they're accessible from `http://localhost:8080/plugin/images/icons`. However, when I include the plugin in a Grails app, they are now packaged into this url: `http://localhost:8080/myapp/plugins/my-plugin-1.0.0/images/icons/sample.png`.

Can someone explain what is going on here? I really want those assets accessible from `/images/icons`/ not `/plugins/plugin-version/images/icons`.

Comment: I have been looking into this myself lately and although i'm not quite sure how to implement it, I have a strong suspicion that the answer lies within creating custom URL mappings in the UrlMappings.groovy file under the conf directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to add the resource plugin back into Grails (along with the asset pipeline). This is how the image linking works now in my app:

```
<r:img dir="images" file="sample.png" plugin="myPlugin"/>
```

Note the `plugin` attribute. That's critical.